# Retrieve a certain number of records with the same field mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySql 5.X, where the identifiers are repeated repeatedly according to the date. I need to recover the first 2 records for each identifier.

example:

```
     name         year      month   
     xxxx         2019        8 
     xxxx         2019        7 
     xxxx         2019        6 
     xxxx         2019        5 
     ....         ....        ..
     zzzz         2019        5
     zzzz         2019        4
     zzzz         2019        3
     zzzz         2019        2
     ....         ....        ..
```

expected result:

```
      name         year      month
      xxxx         2019        8 
      xxxx         2019        7 
      zzzz         2019        5
      zzzz         2019        4
      other ...
```

I need to retrieve the first two records for each name, it is not valid to do so with date clauses.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.x you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to assign numbers to rows. Then filtering the ones you need is easy. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select
    name, year, month,
    row_number() over(partition by name order by year desc, month desc) as rn
  from t
  ) x
where rn <= 2
order by name, year desc, month desc
```

Comment: Sorry, i specify the version of mysql: 5.7

Comment: As far as I can think of, this can be solved with a) lateral queries, b) window functions, or c) CTEs. MySQL 5.x doesn't have any of those. The only other option I can see is assigning row numbers using MySQL variables (the `@a` thingy). However, I'm no expert on those; if you really need this you may want to research these variables. It sounds to me it could work for this.

Comment: solved in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645949/emulating-partition-over-with-mysql-5-7/58646157#58646157. thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

First part will fetch the 1st record for each year & month from the table.
Second part will fetch the 2nd record for each year & month.

```
    SELECT a.name, 
        a.year, 
        a.month 
    FROM   test a 
    GROUP  BY a.name, 
            a.year

    UNION          

    SELECT a.name, 
        a.year, 
        (SELECT month 
            FROM   test b 
            WHERE  b.name = a.name 
                AND b.year = a.year 
            LIMIT  1, 1) AS Month 
    FROM   test a 
    GROUP  BY a.name, 
            a.year ;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Sathish G. The query returns all results, not just two for each name