# Emulating PARTITION OVER with MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySql 5.7, where the names are repeated according to the date. I need to recover the first 2 records for each name.

example:

```
 name         year      month   
 xxxx         2019        8 
 xxxx         2019        7 
 xxxx         2019        6 
 xxxx         2019        5 
 ....         ....        ..
 zzzz         2019        5
 zzzz         2019        4
 zzzz         2019        3
 zzzz         2019        2
 ....         ....        ..
```

expected result:

```
  name         year      month
  xxxx         2019        8 
  xxxx         2019        7 
  zzzz         2019        5
  zzzz         2019        4
  other ...
```

I need to retrieve the first two records for each name, it is not valid to do so with date clauses.

the query I try to emulate:

```
SELECT
 name, year, month
FROM (
SELECT
    *,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC)
FROM
    table
) a
WHERE row_number <= 2
```

thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Before MySQL 8.0 you can't use window functions like `ROW_NUMBER`. But you can use [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) instead to emulate the `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
SELECT name, year, month FROM (
  SELECT *, IF(@prev <> name, @rn:=0,@rn), @prev:=name, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rn
  FROM example, (SELECT @rn:=0) rn, (SELECT @prev:='') prev
  ORDER BY name ASC, year DESC, month DESC
) t WHERE rn <= 2;
```

Since MySQL 8.0 this query is much easier, using the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) function:

```
SELECT name, year, month FROM (
  SELECT name, year, month, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC) AS rn
  FROM example
) t WHERE rn <= 2;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d407791fb6def7beffcc5a4199797a9d)

---

**What if your partition by has two columns?**

Using MySQL 5.7 with used-defined variables (and without `ROW_NUMBER`):

```
-- using two columns on the partition (name and year)
SELECT name, year, month FROM (
    SELECT *, IF(@prev <> name + year, @rn:=0,@rn), @prev:=name + year, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rn
    FROM example, (SELECT @rn:=0)rn, (SELECT @prev:='')prev
    ORDER BY name ASC, year DESC, month DESC
)t WHERE rn <= 2;
```

Using MySQL 8.0 with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
-- using two columns on the partition (name and year)
SELECT name, year, month FROM (
  SELECT name, year, month, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, year ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC) AS rn
  FROM example
)t WHERE rn <= 2;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=842ed21743c1e8366268865806126e09)

Comment: What if your partition by has two columns? :)

Comment: I have to change the order of if() statement of the script version of MySQL 5.7 to make the row number work as expect. Btw, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to implementing the `PARTITION BY` clause using MySQL 5.7 local variable assignments would be to use JSON as follows:

```sql
SELECT
  *,
  json_extract(
    @rn := json_set(
      @rn, @path := concat('$."', name, '"'), 
      (coalesce(json_extract(@rn, @path), 0) + 1)
    ), 
    @path
  ) AS rn
FROM table, (SELECT @rn := '{}') r
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC;
```

The benefit of this approach is that the `PARTITION BY` clause does not affect the ordering of the query as a whole.