# Mysql Select X rows after specific match

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I'm trying to write a select statement in MySQL to get 5 rows after I get my match then sum how many times those numbers were repeated.

Example:

Raw Table

| id | number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 14 |
| 5 | 11 |
| 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 9 | 10 |
| 10 | 9 |
| 11 | 0 |
| 12 | 5 |
| 13 | 3 |
| 14 | 11 |
| 15 | 0 |

I need to find every row with the number 0, then after that select and show 5 rows after and counting the appearance of the numbers.
How can I select the numbers and get the count as a result?

The result of the first select should be like this:

| id | number |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 14 |
| 5 | 11 |
| 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 9 | 10 |
| 10 | 9 |
| 11 | 0 |
| 12 | 5 |
| 13 | 3 |
| 14 | 11 |
| 15 | 0 |

The result of the count for every number in the last query.

| Number | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | 2 |
| 14 | 1 |
| 11 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |

Comment: One is showing the records, while other is showing the result of an aggregate function. Both results can't be printed out simultaneously in a single query. You need 2 separate queries for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a demo to get expected results:

Select numbers:

```
SELECT id, number
FROM (
 SELECT b.id, b.number, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.id ASC) r
 FROM numbers a
 JOIN numbers b ON a.id < b.id
 WHERE a.number = 0
) t WHERE t.r <= 5
ORDER BY id
```

Count numbers:

```
WITH n AS (
 SELECT id, number
 FROM (
  SELECT b.id, b.number, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.id ASC) r
  FROM numbers a
  JOIN numbers b ON a.id < b.id
  WHERE a.number = 0
 ) t WHERE t.r <= 5
)
SELECT number, COUNT(*) counts
FROM n
GROUP BY number
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
id INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
number INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO numbers ( number ) VALUES (1),(0),(9),(14),(11),(0),(3),(4),(10),(9),(0),(5),(3),(11),(0);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1fe71080cfb27680eb2a37b721e5de2d

**Update for MySQL v5.7**

```
SELECT n.*
FROM numbers n
JOIN (
 SELECT a.id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(b.id ORDER BY b.id SEPARATOR ','), ',', 5) selections
 FROM numbers a
 JOIN numbers b ON a.id < b.id
 WHERE a.number = 0
 GROUP BY a.id
) t ON FIND_IN_SET(n.id, t.selections)
ORDER BY n.id
```

---

```
SELECT n.number, COUNT(*) counts
FROM numbers n
JOIN (
 SELECT a.id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(b.id ORDER BY b.id SEPARATOR ','), ',', 5) selections
 FROM numbers a
 JOIN numbers b ON a.id < b.id
 WHERE a.number = 0
 GROUP BY a.id
) t ON FIND_IN_SET(n.id, t.selections)
GROUP BY n.number
ORDER BY n.number
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3be09acab5cd696ec4b01585eb5c32ed

Comment: Thank you @ProGu, but the MySql version is 5.7 :(, it seems "OVER" is not supported.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.id ASC) r
 FROM numbers a
 JOIN numbers b ON a.id ' at line 3

I've checked this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645949/emulating-partition-over-with-mysql-5-7

How to put the variables according to my project?

Comment: @KonradSoares Let me update answer for v5.7

Comment: If using variables, refer to https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=839ac5ac3fa3ff8370f0f160ae2912c6

Comment: another question, how to list only 3 "winners" (greater count)  from the 15 numbers?

Comment: ORDER BY counts DESC LIMIT 3