# What is the other way to get result without using MYSQL ROW_NUMBER Function with PARTITION and multiple group by to reset row count

Tags: mysql, row-number, mysql-variables

```
select 
   Id,request_id,key_skill_id, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY skill_id 
                      ORDER BY request_id,skill_id) sequence 
from report  
where id= x 
GROUP by request_id, skill_id 
order by  request_id,skill_id ;
```

I tried to write something like the following, but the result is not the same:

select
id,
request_id,
@skill_id :=skill_id as skill_id,
@row_number :=
CASE
WHEN  @skill_id = skill_id THEN @row_number+1
ELSE 1
END AS row_number
from report,
(SELECT @row_number := 0, @skill_id := '') as t
where id =x
GROUP by request_id, skill_id
order by request_id, skill_id;

Comment: You can [use variables to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58646157/1048425), but unless you are using a version of MySQL that doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER()` I have no idea why you would want to look for an alternative.

Comment: I am looking other option  because of my  mysql server doesn't support ROW_NUMBER() function here is my equivent query am try to write but result is not same

Answer (score 1):

The original window function strikes me as a bit odd but I confess that I don't use these functions too frequently being confined to MySQL 5.7 myself. The `PARTITION BY` clause specifies the `key_skill_id` column so re-numbering 1, 2, 3, etc. will be done on those rows with identical `key_skill_id` column values. But then there is a final `ORDER` clause at the very end of the SQL that re-sorts the results so that rows with the same `key_skill_id` will not *in general* be together (unless, for example, there was only a single value of `feedback_request_id` being selected).

To do the initial numbering the rows, however, the table must first be sorted by `key_skill_id` and then `feedback_request_id`. The purpose of the `GROUP BY` clause in the original SQL is to function as an equivalent of a `SELECT DISTINCT` query, which can't be used because the added row number column guarantees that each row is distinct. The reason why the `GROUP BY` works is that it is applied *before* the `ROW_NUMBER` window function is performed whereas the `SELECT DISTINCT` implied filtering would be applied *after* the `ROW_NUMBER` function is performed.

Given you have provided no table definitions, data, expected output, etc. I was unable to test the following. This is my best guess:

```sql
select
    x.*,
    @row_number :=
      CASE
         WHEN  @key_skill_id = x.key_skill_id THEN @row_number+1
         ELSE 1
      END AS sequence,
    @key_skill_id = x.key_skill_id
from (
    select distinct /* to emulate group by */
       candidateId,
       feedback_id,
       key_skill_id
       from newFeedbackReport
       where candidate_id = 2501
       order by key_skill_id, feedback_request /* this is not a mistake */
) x,
(SELECT @row_number := 0, @key_skill_id := '') as t
order by feedback_request_id, key_skill_id;
```