# Mysql Select SUM(Distinct)

Tags: mysql

I have a table in the database like below :

| transDate | ref | total_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-03 | 003 | 200 |
| 2022-11-05 | 003 | 200 |
| 2022-11-08 | 002 | 200 |
| 2022-10-16 | 001 | 150 |

I had tried a few coding lines and below is one of them

```
SELECT YEAR(transDate) as year, 
       MONTH(transDate) as month,
       SUM(DISTINCT total_price) as sum_of_total_price  
  FROM table 
 GROUP BY YEAR(transDate), MONTH(transDate) 
 ORDER BY YEAR(transDate), MONTH(transDate) ASC
```

I want to SUM the `total_price` for every ref 003,002 and 001. But for ref:003 I just want to take
200 only because of duplicate value.

The final result I want to show by year and date like below.

| Year/date | sum_of_total_price |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11 | 400 |
| 2022-10 | 150 |

Your kind help much appreciate.tq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the distinct values, then aggregate on the outer query.

```
 select mt.transDate,
        sum(mt.total_price) as sum_of_total_price
 from  (select transDate,
               ref,
               total_price
        from my_table
        group by transDate,ref,total_price
       ) as mt
group by transDate;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/dDNDFBjv

**Edit**. OP changed the logic of the question I will leave previous answer and add the updated query below:

```
select transDate ,
       sum(mt.total_price) as sum_of_total_price
from  ( select DATE_FORMAT(transDate, '%Y-%m') as transDate ,
               ref,
               total_price
        from my_table
        group by DATE_FORMAT(transDate, '%Y-%m'),ref,total_price
      ) as mt
group by transDate;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/t5ydbLTV

**Edit2**, Emulate ROW_NUMBER , all credits to [Sebastian Brosch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645949/emulating-partition-over-with-mysql-5-7)

```
select DATE_FORMAT(transDate, '%Y-%m') as transDate ,
       sum(mt.total_price) as sum_of_total_price
from ( SELECT *, 
              IF(@prev <> ref, @rn:=0,@rn), @prev:=ref, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rn
       FROM my_table, (SELECT @rn:=0) rn, (SELECT @prev:='') prev
       ORDER BY transDate ASC
     ) mt 
WHERE rn = 1
group by DATE_FORMAT(transDate, '%Y-%m');
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/6aASUamZ

Comment: Hi bro..thanks for the reply and i get the result :)...wanna ask further lets say ref:003 having 200 (1st row),100(2nd row) -- both rows share the same ref. I want to take the 1st row only..is it possible? because in  future any changes in particular ref..it will be affected the 1st row only.

Comment: @EisZych yes, use row_number. https://dbfiddle.uk/xdQcVwn0

Comment: Just click the link given..sorry n tq bro 

Comment: hi sorry again..for this  "yes, use row_number. dbfiddle.uk/xdQcVwn0 "..i had tried but nothing happens due to mysql version is lower than 8.0..how to alter syntax near row_number() OVER PARTITION?..sorry

Comment: @EisZych check the last edit

Comment: Hi bro..the edited code works fine..thanks for your time..really2 appreciate it :)